# MapQuest API integration

Tags: php, curl, mapquest

Would you please let me know is there any API for getting business data(name, address, phone, website and so on) using mapquest.

I used this API for fetch information:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.mapquestapi.com/search/v4/place?sort=relevance&feedback=false&key=Key&q=".$businessname);
```

But it returns only the address info and not the phone and website infos so I need to also find out these details.

Please pass me only API link so I can implement it.

Answer (score -1):

The old [search/v2](https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/search-api/v2/) may have the information you're looking for.